# Chain of points on a plane with spacing constraints, find minimum solution

Tags: geometry

For a series of **(n+1)** points placed on a $2D$ plane each with coordinates **(x,y)**, I want update their positions to solve for the following constraint:
the distance between the **nth** and **(n+1)th** point should be a specified euclidean distance (vector of **n** values).

The solution should minimise the change in position:
minimise **S** = sum(norm(change in **(x,y)** position)).

I'm looking for an algorithm that finds the new point positions, when the original point positions and vector of specified distances are known. For my application the original points will be located close to the solution. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it is better to state the optimization problem more clearly:

Let $\mathbf{r} = \{r_1,r_2,...,r_n\}$ be the specified distances between each pair of points.

Let $\mathbf{x} = \{x_1,x_2,...,x_n,x_{n+1}\}$ be the horizontal coordinates of each point.

Let $\mathbf{y} = \{y_1,y_2,...,y_n,y_{n+1}\}$ be the vertical coordinates of each point.

Let $\mathbf{a} = \{a_1,a_2,...,a_n,a_{n+1}\}$ be the design variables corresponding to how much each horizontal coordinate moves.

Let $\mathbf{b} = \{b_1,b_2,...,b_n,b_{n+1}\}$ be the design variables corresponding to how much each vertical coordinate moves.

Therefore, we want to solve the following problem:

$\boxed{\text{minimize } S(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} {a_i}^2 + {b_i}^2\\
\text{such that } h_i(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}) = (x_i + a_i - x_{i+1} - a_{i+1})^2 + (y_i + b_i - y_{i+1} - b_{i+1})^2 - r_i^2 = 0\;\;,\;\forall i \in \{1,2,...,n\}}$

---

We have the following derivatives for each function:

$\nabla S = 2\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\\vdots\\a_{n+1}\\b_1\\b_2\\\vdots\\b_{n+1}\end{bmatrix}$

$\nabla h_i = 2\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\\vdots\\(x_i+a_i-x_{i+1}-a_{i+1})\\-(x_i+a_i-x_{i+1}-a_{i+1})\\\vdots\\(y_i+b_i-y_{i+1}-b_{i+1})\\-(y_i+b_i-y_{i+1}-b_{i+1})\\\vdots\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

---

You can then solve it using any gradient-based method, for example: using KKT optimality criteria; or penalty methods for the constraints.

Comment: Great, I think I can implement a numerical method. Does that mean there isn't a direct solution? I had envisioned something like least squares regression using the pseudo inverse, except I don't have the algebra skills. Thanks for your answer Daniel.

Comment: By "direct solution", do you mean non-iterative? I am not sure, in some cases, the optimality criteria can be enough to obtain a direct solution, it has to be verified. I didn't understand how you would solve this with least squares and pseudo inverse.

Comment: I did mean non-iterative yes. Also, in your answer some of the terms are i+a, should they be i+1?

Comment: Yes, they should, sorry about that. I've just corrected them.